# How programmatically resolve apache velocity variable?

Tags: java, velocity

Velocity documentation [tells](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.7/user-guide.html#variables) that to resolve a variablev a `#set` derective or POJO with corresponding property should be used. Is there a way to provide a custome resolver? E.g. when `$client` appears in template, resolver `go` to database, retrieve `Client` entity, get `name` field and fill `$client` place holder. Does velocity template engine support such extensions?

Answer (score 0):

You may try with the ReferenceInsertionHandler, but its purpose is rather to *filter* (aka modify, alter in some way) displayed values than to *fetch* values from Velocity references.

Such a task would typically be done by the context objects themselves. That is, `$client` can contain an object which *knows* how to fetch and return the client's name on its `toString()` method.

You can also use objects with getters and setters, so that you can write `$client.name` as long as `$client.address`. You'll get yourself doing some kind of [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping). As a side note, there are [existing libraries](http://velosurf.sourceforge.net/) easing this task for Velocity.